# Output of function changes based on whether I include a console.log() within the function

Tags: javascript

I was doing Leetcode's "Container With Most Water" problem and stumbled upon a bizarre situation where the output value of the function changes depending on whether I have included a console.log() in it or not. I am completely baffled and have no idea why this is the case.

Well, I can most certainly expect that the output value of any function under the sun to not change based on whether I have a console.log() included in the function or not. I have pasted the same code into my local vscode, online compilers, and they yielded the same result, which is extremely bizarre. Any help to explain this bizarre phenomenon is appreciated.

Below is the code and the only commented part is the culprit, and will change my output to either "1" or "2" depending on if that line is commented out or not.

```
let c = [1,2,1]

var myFunc = function(height) {
    let maxAmt=0
    let temp
    let highestBar = -1
    let biggestGap = -1
    for (let i = height.length-1;i>=0;i--){
        for(let j = i-1;j>=0;j--){
            if((height[i]>highestBar||height[j]>highestBar)&&((i-j)>biggestGap))
                // culprit culprit console.log() below here
                // console.log('enter');
                if(height[j]<=height[i]){
                    temp=height[j]*(i-j)
                } else if(height[j]>=height[i]){
                    temp=height[i]*(i-j)
                }
                if(maxAmt<temp){
                    maxAmt = temp
                    highestBar = Math.sqrt(maxAmt)
                    biggestGap = i-j
                }
        }
    }
    console.log('max is '+maxAmt);
    return maxAmt
};

console.log(myFunc(c))
```

Comment: The only way we can provide a proper explanation is if you provide a [mre].

Comment: What would be the expected output?

Comment: This is actually my first post so I deeply apologise if I appear ignorant to the usage of this site. Have edited my code in.

Comment: Okay, I found it. There's no curly brace after the preceding if-statement.

Comment: code is right. Thank you so much for the insanely fast response.

Comment: When an if-statement doesn't enclose its successful behavior in a curly brace, only the next statement group is executed. When the `console.log` is commented out, the if statement if the one that's executed. Otherwise, the `console.log` runs.